# Kylo and nifi usage for ETL

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, kylo

We have started to explore and use Nifi for data flow as a basic ETL tool.
Got to know about Kylo as a datalake specific tool which works over Nifi.

Are there any industry usage and pattern where Kylo is being used Or any article giving its use case/preference over custom Hadoop components like Nifi/Spark ?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following two resources:

1) [Kylo's website](https://kylo.io/): The home page lists domains where Kylo is being used.

2) [Kylo FAQs](http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/KyloFrequentlyAskedQuestions.html): Useful information that can help you understand Kylo's architecture and comparison with other tools.

Kylo is designed to work with NiFi and Spark, and does not replace them. You can build custom Spark jobs and execute them via ExecuteSparkJob NiFi processor provided by Kylo.

Comment: FWIW, there's a standard Spark processor in NiFi now, since v1.5.0 as well http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-livy-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.livy.ExecuteSparkInteractive/index.html